# gem update fail - windows

Tags: ruby, windows

```
ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\myname>gem update
Updating installed gems
Updating bigdecimal
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bigdecimal:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161222-9476-ivo88e.rb extconf.rb
```

checking for labs() in stdlib.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

```
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:735:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1020:in `block in have_func'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1019:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I am trying to update the libary on ruby, but its telling me I need to install develpment tools first.

I have downloaded the dev kit and followed these steps:

```
We need to specify a folder where we’re going to permanently install the 
DevKit. I recommend installing it in the root of your hard drive, at 
“C:\RubyDevKit“. (Don’t use spaces in the directory name.)
```

Now we need to make the DevKit tools available to Ruby.

```
Back in your command prompt, change to the the DevKit directory. 
(“Directory” is another name for a folder.) Type “cd C:\RubyDevKit“, or 
whatever other directory name you installed it in.
Next we need to run a Ruby script to initialize the DevKit setup. Type “ruby 
dk.rb init“.
Now we’ll tell that same script to add the DevKit to our Ruby installation. 
Type “ruby dk.rb install“.
```

But still when I go into cmd ruby and gem update I recieve the error at the top :(

Any one know where I am going wrong? I am following a lynda course in my path to becomming a full stack web developer and this is now a road block!

Thanks guys

Comment: Check config.yml in your devkit folder and make sure it has the correct base path to your ruby installation.

Comment: check to make sure that devkit is added to your path correctly